# CRM 2011 Claims Based Authentication with Asp.Net Membership Provider

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

This is possible in SharePoint 2010 but is it doable in CRM 2011?  Or am I required to use ADFS?  I'm assuming it is however I'm unable to find any guidance on how to accomplish it.

Any advice is appreciated.

Jason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the Implementation Guide of Dynamics CRM 2011 it *could* be possible to use your own claims provider.

> When you configure Microsoft Dynamics CRM for Internet-facing access, Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 requires federated services that support claims-based authentication. **We recommend Active Directory Federation Services 2.0.**

See [Federation and claims-based authentication support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh699832.aspx)